# Why my mm:ss.000 value gets changed automaticaly?

Tags: microsoft-excel, office365

I'm using the custom format `mm:ss,000` in a table for storing lap times BUT every time I input a time in a cell it gets automaticaly changed to another value, for example:

- if I insert the time `02:20,245` what I get after hovering on it is the time `00:02:20`
- if I insert `03:30:032` what I see is `00:03:30`

I'm using this value in a table (and I don't know how table works properly), and the time from the table are sent to a pivot table (I also never used pivot tables) that I should use for making a graph.

I don't know what could be the cause, the columns of the table and on the pivot table are set to be in the custom format `mm:ss,000` but it doesn't work and I need them to be in this format for more easily elaboration.

I'm open to any solution?

What I type before pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>:
[image: Before enter]

This is the same cell after I press <kbd>Enter</kbd>:
[image: After enter]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the formula bar in Excel cannot be configured to display milliseconds when in a time format.

If you want your pivot table to display as the custom format, you'll need to format your source table as `General` and then format your pivot table columns as `mm:ss,000`